# Virtual method declared in Class but not defined

Tags: c++, virtual, linker-errors, defined

My purpose is to find all places where some function is called.
So I define new class inherence from it, and make the function inaccessible.
But I don't define the method, and I got link error.

Here is the code:

*A.hpp*:

```
#ifndef _A_HPP
#define _A_HPP
class _declspec(dllexport) A 
{
public:
    virtual void f1();
};
class _declspec(dllexport) B: public A 
{
private:
    void f1();
};
#endif
```

*A.cpp*:

```
#include "A.hpp"
 void A::f1(){}
```

*program.cpp*:

```
#include "A.hpp"

int main(void )
{
    A a;
    a.f1();
    return 0;
}
```

`B::f1()` is never called , but I still have a link error.
**But if you remove `_declspec(dllexport)` it builds OK.**

Comment: and the error says???

Comment: (1) You cannot make an accessible function inaccessible (2) A whole new class has no effect on the compilation of the rest of the program whatsoever (3) All virtual functions must be defined whether they are called or not.

Comment: you have missing ; after } of class

Comment: @n.m. - I still get the same error even changing `private` to `public` so I think it is not that

Comment: You have not one, not two, but three errors in your attempt to identify call sites. Only one if them is related to your compilation/link error.

Comment: when I copy pasted your code (with ; added) am not getting any error... do you have some other code? can you copy the exact error log

Comment: @Renjith sorry about the code, I am testing my code

Comment: @n.m. All virtual functions must be defined whether they are called or not is not true, if you remove _declspec(dllexport)

Comment: All virtual functions must be defined whether they are called or not. It's true. Make what you want of it.

Comment: Create a new project specifying DLL and have a look at the example code.  That is basically how you used _declspec(dllexport) and _declspec(dllimport).

Comment: @cup Will the resulting dll be usable as is? Have you tried to actually run a program that uses it?

Comment: Yes it is usable.  I have actually tried using the resultant .dll and .lib with another program and it works - the global variable, the standalone function and the class.

Comment: @cup The standard explicitly disallows it, without requiring a diagnostic (3.2 basic.def.odr pp. 2,3). The compiler just lets you get away with it, for whatever reason.

Comment: @n.m I misunderstood your question - I think you meant not declaring a function in a DLL.  I thought you were asking about the wizard generated code.  If it is the wizard generated code - that works.  If it is not declaring the function in the DLL, then it doesn't link.

Comment: @Abhineet `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __thiscall B::f1(void)" (?f1@B@@EAEXXZ)`

Comment: @Renjith the code is updated

Answer (score 1):

The function is referenced by a virtual function table for class A.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

You cannot have virtual functions (aside from pure virtual functions) that are undefined. They must be defined such that the virtual table is defined.

Making the function private is also futile as simply calling (&A).f1() will call B::f1().

---

Edit to clarify about your edit, compiling the following with no optimizations,

```
struct Foo { virtual void foo(); };
struct Goo : public Foo { void foo() {} };

int main()
{
        Goo f;
        return 0;
}
```

results in a linker error (using GCC),

```
undefined reference to `typeinfo for Foo'
```

which is as expected. What happens in your case with the removed export is that MSVC probably cheating. It sees the entire class, and all its uses and does not generate a virtual table. It optimizes it out. It knows that you are not using that virtual table in external code, so it does not bother with it.

I also get no error if I compile with optimization turned on for exactly the same reason.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you misunderstand my code,`Goo` is never used.

Comment: That is quite irrelevant whether it is Foo or Goo.